# Issues with dokku deployment issue with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokku

When I tried to deploy ruby-rails-sample it all went fine, but when tried to deploy my app got

```
-----> Building app from herokuish...
remote: /var/lib/dokku/plugins/enabled/00_dokku-standard/commands: line 20: docker: command not found
remote: /var/lib/dokku/plugins/enabled/00_dokku-standard/commands: line 20: tar: command not found
```

Is there any env var I should check? (i copied my vars from heroku)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that I had a PATH env var that made all the mess, watch out all of you try to move from heroku to dokku, don't copy paste all env vars..